# Need to redirect a page immediately after sending out a .post request with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

still learning so be gentle ;) - 
What was happening on my site was the following:

1. Send an AJAX POST request to update the sql database with new event
   attendees
2. Send out some email notifications
3. Wait for server to return "ok" for emails sent
4. Reload the page to show it with the new attendees

Turns out sending out emails can take up to 5 seconds or more, and I don't want the user to have to wait for it to complete. What I'm trying to do now is instead to:

1. Send AJAX POST request for sql
2. Send out server request for email notifications
3. Reload page before server responds for #2.

I tried posting:

```
window.location.replace("");
```

before

```
$.post(
'/_x_/email/tag',
    {
    event_id: event_id,
    tagged_id: tag_id,
    type: 'tag_event_ongoing'
    }
);
```

But server would still wait for a response.
I've also tried:

```
document.open();
$.get("",function(data) {
   document.write(data);
})
document.close();
```

before the post request - this reloads the page, but for some reason none of the javascript works unless I manually reload.

EDIT: I've also tried using a proper $.ajax() call:

```
var email = $.ajax({
url: '/_x_/email/tag',
type: 'POST',
data: {
    event_id: event_id,
    tagged_id: tag_id,
    type: 'tag_event_ongoing'
},
dataType: "json",
success: function (res) {
    window.location.replace("");
}
});
```

ADDITIONAL NOTE: 
My code for emailing is written as the callback for the sql insert - thus emails are only sent when the SQL insert is successful. I don't think it matters, but just in case.

Anyone know how I can solve this?

Answer (score 1):

You should configure your server platform to send the e-mails in the background. All the server should do is acknowledge the receipt of information from the ajax post, spawn the mailer process in the background, and let the user be on their merry way. The only reason I can think of when this isn't possible is if the page you're redirecting to depends on those e-mails being sent. This would require some sort of exception notification or a way of "retrying" the process in case of errors.

This is the proper way to approach this problem, but you could probably hack it with Javascript, I guess.

Comment: Thanks Adam - do you have a suggestion on how to achieve the background process for emails? I'm on a LAMP stack - would it be to use a chron script that reads off something like an "email" table? Would be great if you could share a plugin, or site that explains how I could do this. Thank you!

Comment: By LAMP stack, do you mean your application is written in PHP? If that's the case, on receipt of the ajax post, quickly store your data in an e-mail table. You will then need a cron job, which can be a php script if you like (probably easiest), which you should probably execute every hour. This script will read "pending" e-mails from the database and send them one-by-one. On successful send, un-flag it as pending, and continue on. You may also want to keep track of send attempts. Perhaps after 3 send attempts, flag the record as failed. That should be enough to get you started.

Answer (score 0):

I would look into using the full blown `$.ajax`[call](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) instead of a `post`. This will give you much more control because there are several ajax events that you can hook in to.

You could also return from the server the list of new event attendees, then you could skip reloading the page entirely. If you reload the entire page, you may end up in a situation where you can't be sure if or when an AJAX call will complete.

Are you making two separate AJAX calls for items 1 and 2 or are you doing both actions in one call to the server? If you're doing it all in one function, then you can split the sever-side calls into two functions and make two discrete ajax calls on the client. That way, when number 1 comes back, you can update the screen without waiting for number 2.

This is the best I can do with the small amount of code you've provided.

Comment: I tried $.ajax and using the "success" event, but it still seemed to wait for the server to return the response before redirecting. I'll append the code to my post.

Comment: Also, I am in fact currently sending two separate AJAX calls, and am attempting to do what you're describing. My problem is that I can't seem to do it - I can't seem to update the screen without waiting for number 2.

Comment: In that case, I would return the list of new event attendees after you update the database and just redraw the screen when AJAX call number 1 comes back. Then you wouldn't have to refresh the screen and could avoid this whole problem entirely.

Comment: My problem is that I don't know how to do the screen refresh. Do you know what code or function I should be using? I tried the options outlined above.

Comment: My suggestion is to change your emailing logic so that sending emails is done asynchronously. I would also return the data back to the client to the success callback of your AJAX call. That way you wouldn't have to reload the page just to update the list of attendees and you wouldn't have to wait on the emailing logic.

Answer (score 0):

Use the callback as specified in jQuery.post()... [, success(data, textStatus, jqXHR). to let you know when the data is posted, and go on your merry way serving what the user wants to do next.

Comment: I tried using the success callback, however it still seems to wait for the server to respond - I want to act before the server responds. Essentially to "move on" while the server is still "processing". Is that was "success" is supposed to do? Maybe my syntax isn't right then? (I've appended the code above. Thank you!)